# Could we access local host from Geny Motion?

Tags: android, genymotion

Could we access local host from Geny Motion like using IP 10.0.2.2 on Android Virtual Device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access your localhost through Genymotion is using your PC IP address. to get your IP address go to:

```
start -> cmd -> ipconfig
```

then search for IPv4, copy the IP and paste it in your URL. It should looks like the following:

String `YourURL = "http://192.168.0.101/your_script_location.php";`